# Manually entering what to search for

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a program that manually loops through files in a folder and searches for keywords, telling you which file has them.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Where? ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        LoopedData(input);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void LoopedData(string path)
    {
        string[] files;
        string[] directories;
        string lineToFind = keyword;
        files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            int line = 1;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                // read file line by line 
                string lineRead;
                while ((lineRead = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if ( lineRead.Contains(lineToFind))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File {0}, line: {1}", file, lineRead);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    }
                    line++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finished.....");
            Console.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine(file);
            // look for string here
        }

        directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            // Process each directory recursively
            LoopedData(directory);
        }
    }

}
```

I have been able to manually enter which folders to search in but I am having difficulty in creating a similar way to do it for the keyword. I have tried referencing it in the Main class, with no success. I need a fresh pair of eyes.

Any search I try doesn't yield helpful results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already know what to do. Your doing it correctly for the path. To get the `keyword` from the user, just do the same thing as for the path:

```
static void Main()
{
    string path = "";
    string keyword = "";

    Console.WriteLine("Where? "); // read path
    path = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("What? "); // read keyword
    keyword = Console.ReadLine();
    LoopedData(input, keyword);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And change your `LoopedData`'s signature like that to pass the `keyword` as parameter:

```
static void LoopedData(string path, string keywork)
{
    // your code
}
```